# Create a list that shows values that did and did not occur

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a set of data

```
data = {1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4}
```

and another set of data

```
datakey = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

I then use CountBy[] and Sort[] to sort data[] into ascending order and to show count of data[] against datakey[]

```
CountsBy[Sort[data], datakey]
```

Running this shows

```
<|{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}[1] -> 2, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}[2] ->  2, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}[4] -> 3|>
```

This shows that there are 2 amounts of 1, 2 amounts of 2 etc.

I have tried a similar approach using Tally[]

```
Tally[Sort[data]]
```

which returns

```
{{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {4, 3}}
```

What i would like to show is a list that contains the counts of what is present and not present.

Such that it shows

<|[1] -> 2, [2] -> 2, [3] -> 0, [4] -> 3|>

Where it shows the counts of what is in the list and what isnt.

Thank you for your time,

Comment: You might need `Tally`.

Comment: Something like `AssociationThread[datakey, Lookup[Counts[data], datakey, 0]]` or `Merge[{AssociationThread[datakey, 0], Counts[data]}, Max]`?

Comment: Maybe you will find `PositionIndex` useful...

Comment: @J.M.'stechnicaldifficulties this works perfectlty, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As recommended by @J.M.'stechnicaldifficulties

```
AssociationThread[datakey, Lookup[Counts[data], datakey, 0]]
```

produces the result

```
<|1 -> 2, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 0, 4 -> 3, 5 -> 0, 6 -> 0|>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

I think you will find the following much faster for large cases.

```
With[{t = Tally[Join[datakey, data]]}, Transpose[Transpose[t] - {0, 1}]]
```

For example:

```
data = RandomChoice[RandomInteger[{1, 1000000}, 1000000], 10000000];
datakey = Range@1000000;
Length@Union@data

r1 = AssociationThread[datakey, 
    Lookup[Counts[data], datakey, 0]]; // AbsoluteTiming
r2 = With[{t = Tally[Join[datakey, data]]}, 
    Transpose[Transpose[t] - {0, 1}]]; // AbsoluteTiming

(r1 // Values) == r2[[All, 2]]
```

> 2.14736
>
> 0.176966
>
> True